# How could Monero profit from TumbleMoneroWimble?

Tags: privacy, scalability, mimblewimble

Core developer fluffypony on Twitter recently published a link to his [whitepaper on TumbleMoneroWimble](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8e2cyuwjrt3didg/beigegreenpaper.pdf?dl=0), "One-time Ring Signature Scalable Off-Chain Untraceable Instant and MimbleWimble".

Since the use cases listed on page 52 are very interesting, could someone please explain the mechanism in easy words? Especially the instant transactions and micropayments would be very interesting and how can they still can be private.

Comment: While the TumbleMoneroWimble paper is fake, TumbleBit does private instant micropayments.
https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/575.pdf

Comment: Thanks, weekend time and I just got it on my mobile and couldn't really check it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whitepaper is fake, never meant to be taken seriously.

Quoting @fluffypony's [followup tweet](https://twitter.com/fluffyponyza/status/842469768116486150):

> Don't take the 3 papers I tweeted as serious, I used the Koinster whitepaper generator for altcoin-quality papers: https://whitepaper.koinster.com/

Comment: Omg, weekend time and I got the link from a friend on my mobile, so just looked over it...